Why are there "no returns" in my point cloud and am not able to display or process it in lidR?
I have a point cloud I collected and converted to a .las in the proprietary software "FARO Connect".  I am able to visualize the point cloud in the software.  However, when taking the .las file to the lidR package to preprocess it, it reads that it has as an error below:

Checking ReturnNumber validity...
⚠ Invalid data: 182586656 points with a return number equal to 0 found.

How can it not have any returns if I am able to visualize it elsewhere and are there any work arounds to resolve this?

There is no error, it is a warning. It tells you that the LAS file does not respect the LAS specifications. The attribute return number is equal to 0 for all points (182586656). Is it a big deal? It depends if your sensor is supposed to be able to return multiple returns. If not, all return number should be 1 instead of 0.
